# org.glassfish.json.JsonStringImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonArray

Tags: java, json, glassfish

I have this piece of code:

```
JsonObject fg = null;
try{
      fg =  message.getJson();  //gettng the JSON object from the client
      System.out.println("JSONGOBJECT IS HERE:   "+fg);

      JsonArray arr1 =  fg.getJsonArray("to");  //I get the exception here
      int size =  arr1.length();
      arrays = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(Object o : arr1)
      {
        String user=(o == null ? null : o.toString());
           if (user != null) {
                 arrays.add(user);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Exeption HERE: "+e);
       }
```

I get this exception while I try to access value for "to" parameter from `JsonArray`. I am not using `org.glassfish.json` library anywhere. Have not imported it either.

I have imported only `javax.json`  in my current code. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Hi @simar can you explain the issue more.. also check if org.json.JsonObject is what you are importing ..

Comment: @viraj: I am not even importing it . I have strictly stick to javax.json everywhere and crosschecked multiple times.

Comment: ok.. then there is one possibility which I can guess, its that "to" is a key to json object and we are trying to get it as JSONARRAY..Can you please update what you get at _JSONGOBJECT IS HERE:_ so that we can validate this possibility.

Answer (score 4):

The error occurred because you tried to convert `number` into `string`.

This will work for sure.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) 
jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get(key).toString();
```

Get object in a generic way.

Answer (score 0):

Not  sure what the  data structure  of the  message object you are getting from the   client,  to determine if the "to" object  is an  array  or  string. You could   provide  more info here.   The  exception may be due to  the  fact  that the "to" key is  mapped to  a JsonString  ( eg  {to:"thisthat"},  as  opposed to  an  array (eg {to:["this", that"]}). If  this is  the  case ,  the  attempted  casting  of the JsonString  to JsonArray fails, hence the  exception.  May not be spot on here,  but you need to  check the  structure of the message, especially the "to" field.

With  regards to the  org.glassfish.json,  it  is  most  likely  due to your runtime  environment  using   a  glassfish JSON  implementation ( by  default ). This may be  included  as  a jar file ( class loading) . The  json package (javax.json) you import  in your  code  is only    an  interface. And it  will allow you  to compile the  code.  To  run the  code, you will need a  java package implementation (jar)( any for that matter)   that  implements  the  javax.json  interfaces).   You can   explicitly configure your   runtime  environment  to use a  specific json implementation  package, or  your  environment may have a  default  configuration  for javax.json

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by young chisango you might not have included json-api 
implementation.

If you want to run an application with JSON Processing API, declare a dependency on json-api implementation in your maven project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not because you are missing an import, as that would not cause glassfish to be triggered. As mentioned above, the glassfish implementation is called from the javax.json and that is not a problem.

The problem is caused by not having an array in the JsonObject to convert to JsonArray.

One possible example to this could be that in your javascript the array may be declared as an ArrayBuffer rather than an Array.

Go in your javascript to make sure you have an array, and then print out your JsonObject to see what is in it to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by changing my code to use `getBoolean` instead of `getJsonArray`.
So I would recommend trying different datatypes until you find one that works.